# WP Favorite Posts How to add {{wp-favorite-posts}} to my dashboard

Tags: wordpress, plugins

HI Currently i'm using wp 3.05, i add following code
{{wp-favorite-posts}} to page it working fine

while i place the code in my user dashboard
i just shown the code as text which is {{wp-favorite-posts}}

what i already do troubleshoot, reactive this plugin.

**Question: how to place {{wp-favorite-posts}}in my user Theme dashboard**

Appreciate for any suggestion.
thank you in advanced

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the section "Tools - Managing your Blog" on the dashboard and add your favorite posts. Refer to the WordPress codex at http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Panels

Comment: HI Pali, 
Thank you for your suggestion. 
Sorry to confuse you.
actually the dashboard i mentioned was my "themes dashboard" not admin dashboard.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The admin side of Wordpress doesn't parse tags much. If you want to include a plugins functionality into your theme, you'll have to call that plugins functions directly ... or change the plugin's code to also parse the admin content.

Comment: HI Piotr , 
actually i would like to add following code in my "dashboard page template"

{{wp-favorite-posts}}

but after add the code in my dashboard page template  it just appear as text "{{wp-favorite-posts}}" not function.

do you have any idea on how to add {{wp-favorite-posts}} to my dashboard.

thank you in advanced